# DLL load failed in Pycharm/Anaconda/Scipy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, pycharm, anaconda

I'm trying this import from scikit-learn in Pycharm with Anaconda:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
```

but I get this error:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):    File "D:/Google Drive/Apoyo/Proactivo/Afilar la sierra/Programación/Curso Udemy
> >     Tensorflow/pruebas.py", line 4, in 
> >         from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs   File "C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py", line 134, in 
> >         from .base import clone   File "C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 13, in 
> >         from .utils.fixes import signature   File "C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\utils__init__.py", line 11, in 
> >         from .validation import (as_float_array,   File "C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in 
> >          from ..utils.fixes import signature   File "C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 144, in 
> >          from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa   File "D:\Users\alvar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg__init__.py", line 114, in 
> >          from .isolve import *   File "D:\Users\alvar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve__init__.py",
> >     line 6, in 
> >          from .iterative import *   File "D:\Users\alvar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 10, in 
> >          from . import _iterative ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Numpy, Scipy, Scikit-Learn, update it, tried with numpy-mkl... with no success. The code works in Spyder.

Thanks

Comment: Since the error occurs when you are trying to import from scikit-learn, *all* the rest of your code is irrelevant to the question, and it should be removed (removed it myself this time...)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I reinstalled all environment (IDE, Anaconda, TF...) and it works since then.

Thanks you